# Периодичный запуск службы Android

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Встал вопрос о периодичности запускаемых служб. дело в том, что поставленная задача предполагает обновлять некоторые данные в SharedPreferences, обновлять хочу каждые 3 часа. В манифесте прописал службу как отдельный поток:

```
<service
        android:process=":updater.process"
        android:name=".services.android.UpdateSettings"/>
```

Дальше пытался прямо в сервисе сделать фичу, типа в цикле в консоль печатает фразу, ждёт 10сек. `Thread.sleep(10000)` и повторяет цикл. Где-то на 20-ой итерации процесс отваливается (bg anr) и перезапускается. Скажите, почему так происходит и как сделать, чтобы служба отрабатывала полностью без перезагрузок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд эту идею можно реализовать следующим образом:

1) Описать свой `BroadcastReceiver`, который ловит `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` (запуск устройства):

```
<receiver android:name=".AwesomeBroadcastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2) В этом `BroadcastReceiver` в методе `onReceive` определить `Intent` для запуска вашего сервиса и `AlarmManager`, который через 10 минут после запуска устройства каждые 3 часа будет вызывать `Intent`:

```
final long FIRST_START = 10000;

Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AwesomeService.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 
   AwesomeService.SERVICE_ID, startServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(
   AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
   SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + FIRST_START,
   180000,
   contentIntent);
```

Comment: А не сможете подсказать, почему сам сервис перезапускается?

Comment: @PirateNinja, увы, не смогу. Таким способом, как у вас, я не пробовал. А сказать сходу без кода и без отладки - ещё скилл не тот)

Comment: Нашёл в логе
4-13 11:36:05.066 2159-2178/? W/ActivityManager: Timeout executing service

Comment: @PirateNinja А, видимо вы тяжеловесную операцию делаете прямо в `onCreate` или `onStart` сервиса, попробуйте убрать это в `AsyncTask` или в отдельный поток

Comment: Там слип у потока происходит

Comment: @PirateNinja, тогда возможно из-за слипа